# fancybox 3 iframe doesn't work

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I have a problem with FancyBox 3, probably images works perfectly but iframe doesn't.

I've followed all instructions from their site 
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#setup

But video just cant work, whatever I do, I'm getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxM2N.jpg.

I hope some one already had same problems and know answer :D. thx anyway

Comment: What error messages (if any) appear in the Developer Tools console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your code on some webserver or install something like apache on your computer to make it work.

btw, ajax will not work for you developing this way, too.