# Fancybox 3 and testing locally in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, fancybox, internet-explorer-11

I'm developing locally, building pages with FancyBox, and when I test it directly from dreamweaver using real-time preview in IE it works fine, but does not work when I just open the local html file in IE. For reasons not worth getting into I need it to work when I just open the files locally.

In IE the local URL is of course C:\User\Desktop\Site\Index.html, but when I try a link to pull up the fancybox content IE tries to navigate to C:\C:\User\Desktop\Site\Index.html, which is what seems to break it. The fancybox opens with the text "This page can't be displayed." It works fine locally in Chrome though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268516/fancybox-3-iframe-doesnt-work

Comment: I saw that post, and my issue isn't really the same thing. My issue isn't content dependent. Even images generate the same error. In fact it doesn't seem to matter what content fancybox is trying to load, when I'm testing the files locally in IE the popup just returns the "This page can't be displayed" error.

Comment: Have you tried running you code from webserver? Have you checked "Internet options" - there are some restrictions for loading local content. due to security reasons.

Comment: I haven't tried uploading to a server, but I need it to work locally anyway. I'm not actually building a live website, I'm building an html-based interactive content organization/delivery platform, so my end product will be a .exe that runs my "site" locally. I've checked my internet options, but all of the intranet security settings are set to low, and I can't find any other settings that would effect access to local files.

Comment: Well, if you see "The requested content cannot be loaded" message, then the script, obviously, can not load your content. Use developer tools to see what is going on, maybe there is something with your paths,